# WPF TabItem style with define grid(layout)

Tags: c#, wpf

I created style like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="WejStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="Wej"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Adress(hex)" FontSize="15" Margin="10,10,396,355"/>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="WejAdress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,11,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
                            <ComboBoxItem>3A</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>3B</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>3C</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>3D</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>3E</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>3F</ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And use method to add Item to TabControl

```
 public void AddWej()
    {
        var resources = new Resources();
        var style = (Style)resources.FindResource("WejStyle");
        TabCards.Items.Add(style);
    }
```

But it only return `System.Windows.Style`in header and grid.

Can someone tell me what do I wrong?

Edit:

I change AddWej()

```
public void AddWej()
    {
        var resources = new Resources();
        var style = (Style)resources.FindResource("WejStyle");
        var tabItem = new TabItem();
        tabItem.Style = style;
        tabItem.Header = "Wej";
        TabCards.Items.Add(tabItem);
        //dodanie
        cards.Add(new CardWej() { });
    }
```

And code in xaml from:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
```

to

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
<Setter.Value>
<DataTemplate>
```

And it work.

Comment: Try `var style = (Style)this.FindResource("WejStyle");`

Comment: it return exception "Resource "WejStyle" not found."

Comment: `new Resources().FindResource(...)` doesn't make sense. You define it in window resources, so you need that window reference. Where is `AddWej` method located? When and how is it called? We need to see more code.

Comment: I define style in other wpf window, when i moved this style to MainWindow and i use it "this.FindResource("WejStyle");" it dont throw error but i agein have the same reseult "System.Windows.Style".